# Is the probability of the absolute value of a RV being less or equal to a is the same as the probability of it being less than a?

Tags: probability

P( |X| $\leq$ a) = P(a < X < a) ?

Shouldn't it be P(a-1 < X < a-1)?

Comment: $|X|\leq a$ is equivalent to $-a\leq X\leq a$. So no problem here (why in the world would you get the $-1$ ??)

Comment: Your question is kind of weird. The event $|X|\leq a$ is equal to the event $-a\leq X \leq a$! What do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $X$ is **discrete** (for example, if it can only be an integer), then:
$$
P(|X| < a) = P(-a < X < a) = P(-a + 1 \leq X \leq a-1)
$$
Otherwise, if $X$ is **continuous** (for example, if it can be any real number), then:
\begin{align*}
P(|X| < a) &= P(-a < X < a) \\
&= P(-a \leq X < a) \\
&= P(-a < X \leq a) \\
&= P(-a \leq X \leq a) \\
&= P(|X| \leq a)
\end{align*}